# Can't open vs2008 project after vs2015 uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2008 and 2012 installed. Recently, I also installed Visual Studio 2015 but later uninstalled it.  Now I can't open my compact framework project in Visual Studio 2008.

> Unable to read the file project 'Projectname.vbproj'. MSbuildToolsPath is not specified for the ToolsVersion "14.0" defined at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14", or the value specified evaluates to the empty string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As described in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/26/my-visual-studio-2008-is-broken-after-uninstalling-net-framework-4-0.aspx):

> 1. Make sure Visual Studio 2010 is completely uninstalled (go to “Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and features” and make sure it is not listed)
> 2. Make sure the following registry keys do not exist in the machine:
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\4.0
>      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersion\4.0
>
> **Note:** 
>   If you are working on a 64bit OS you will need to delete them from the 32 bit part of the registry. To accomplish that click “Start Menu -> Run…” and type the following command:
>
> %WinDir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe

However in my case I replaced "4.0" for "14.0" and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it has solved an annoying puzzle for me

Comment: This worked for me also. I've just done an edit to provide some context to the link should the link die in the future. Got my upvote though.

Answer (score 10):

Just download and install MSBuild Tools for VS 2015 from the following link
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159
this will fix the problem.